# Modifying data from a React Promise Response impacts globally

Tags: reactjs

I have created a codesandbox with a simplified version of my problem

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-fetch-example-2kjz5

I get some data from a fetch

I want 2 copies of this data, 1 that I want to modify with a SHIFT

The problem: Any changes update my initial data object

Can someone tell me how this is possible? and how can I avoid this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You may need to try deep copy, but I'm not 100% sure, try this https://codesandbox.io/s/react-fetch-example-mdg7o?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Yusufbek suggest, we need to make a deep copy for the data that you want to modify. You can do something like:

```js
export function formatResponsePretty(oldData) {
  // const newData = {
  //   ...oldData
  // };
  const newData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(oldData));

  const obj = { allocations: [] };
  var theRemovedElement = "";
  var ports = [];

  ports = Object.values(newData["liquidity"]["columns"]);
  ports.shift();

  var dataArray = ["liquidity"];

  for (const index of dataArray) {
    for (const i of newData[index]["data"]) {
      theRemovedElement = i.shift();
      if (index === "allocations") {
        obj[index][theRemovedElement] = i;
      } else {
        obj[theRemovedElement] = i;
      }
    }
  }

  return obj;
}
```

Here is the [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-fetch-example-mef7o) (hope the code updated properly :P)

Hope it helps :)